# Extracting domain name from referrer url using regex with Presto DB

Tags: regex, presto

I'm trying to extract the domain name from a list of referrer urls in PrestoDB.  Using the `url_extract_host` function I have a list like below.  I'm stuck trying to get the domain name out of the string.

Presto uses java styled pattern syntax.

I have a list of strings below, all of which should return `google`

`google.com
google.co.il
blog.google.com
blog.google.co.il`

Thanks any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a regular expressions from the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) maintained by Mozilla.

But the expression would be over 100,000 bytes long - there are currently over 8,500 public suffixes, including quite a lot of non-ascii ones, which can be encoded with both UTF-8 and punycode, and your expression would probably need to support both encodings.